# Add an additional field to associated GraphQL field return type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphql, graphql-ruby

I have this GraphQL type in my application.

```rb
module Types
  module MyApp
    class MembersStatus < Types::Base::Object
      field :active, [Types::MyApp::User], null: true
      field :on_leave, [Types::MyApp::User], null: true
      field :status_unknown, [Types::MyApp::User], null: true
    end
  end
end
```

I want to add an additional field to the associated `User` Type for the `on_leave` field.

For example, for the `on_leave` field, I want to have the associated `User` to have an additional field `leave_duration`

`field :leave_duration, Integer, null: true`

So that, I can make queries like below:

```
query memberStatus{
  memberStatus {
    active { name }
    onLeave { name leaveDuration }
    statusUnknown { name } 
  }
}
```

I have looked into https://graphql-ruby.org/type_definitions/extensions.html#customizing-fields this doc but can't implement it yet. Can this be done? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as you described, you need to add the `leave_duration` field to the user type.

```
module Types
  module MyApp
    class UserType
      # other stuff
      field :leave_duration, GraphQL::Types::ISO8601Date, null: true

      # Optional: Define leave_duration if it isn't already a field on the model:
      def leave_duration
        # implementation that returns a date
      end
    end
  end
end
```

It looks like you may have had a typo in the `field()` call, where `:leave_duration` should be a symbol, not a variable or method. That is fixed in the above snippet.

Edit: Regarding your question about conditionally having leave_duration only when on_leave, I would suggest this:

```rb
def leave_duration
  return nil unless object.on_leave

  # implementation that returns a date
end
```

There is a way to hide the field from the schema, which is described here:
https://github.com/rmosolgo/graphql-ruby/issues/893

But it seems way too overkill to me to hide a field based on the presence of another field. I think this is mainly intended to hide fields like `is_admin` for non-admin users.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Yes, this will work. Though this way my userType needs modification. It will be better if I can add the field to the `User` Type only for the `on_leave` field return type. Other times, I don't want the `User` Type to have this field. Can this be done?

Comment: @Md.ImamHossain Edited my answer to hopefully point you in the right direction.

Comment: @Unixmoneky Thank you very much. I did implement the feature as of your first suggestion. I do agree t conditional visibility would be an overkill for this case. I have implemented that in the same project for other use case though. :D